# Saving remote images to local folder via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, file-io, mobile-website, trigger.io

Is it possible to download an image with a specified URL to a folder within the space of the web app, say in `/images`, to be accessed locally?

I say this because I'm writing a mobile web app wrapped with TriggerIO but the native saving functionality is super slow and freezes up the phone in the process, so any touch interactions have a 5+ second delay.

Are there any known javascript options to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: no way with JS. But is possible with some proxy. something like `http://savetodisk.com/?get=http://urlofthepic.jpg and download it on serverside and send it as binary data to user`

Comment: @Garrett: by "native saving functionality" do you mean forge.file.saveURL? Surprised that you've had unresponsiveness... is this iOS or Android?

Comment: @monk iOS — I've had logs that show a wait of up to 7 seconds on an iPhone 5 with full WiFi, but the usual is 1-2 seconds.

[FORGE] 'Saving image: http://files.parse.com/aac0413c-eada-4602-9451-2ee5da7d1241/ae926e6d-fae7-495a-9053-dec8b7eb7522-image.png [0.002s]'
all.js:2[FORGE] 'Saved local copy of http://files.parse.com/aac0413c-eada-4602-9451-2ee5da7d1241/ae926e6d-fae7-495a-9053-dec8b7eb7522-image.png *[7.405s]*'

Here's my code:
debug("Saving " + url);

`forge.file.saveURL(url,
    function(file) {
     debug("Saved " + url, file);`

Comment: any update on this? i'm still having freezing/lag and incredibly slow download speed (even on 4g/wifi).